# mysql join and update

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap

I have an application developed using codeigniter, I have an initial login page that I need users to access, without authentication, then, from this page I want them to be prompted for authentication via LDAP on the server.  The thing is in codeigniter all php files must be within their respective model/view/controller directories.How do I in this case allow access for ldap to the login page but not the rest of the code until authentication.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why your title is completely **NOT** related to LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

throw all your ldap stuff into a new library file and then use it wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

Use a LDAP library for CI and build the rest of the application as you would a typical CI application.

http://dhorrigan.com/blog/article/ldap-library-for-codeigniter/